# Imported Forms popping up when running application even though they haven't been called in the layout/event loop

Tags: python-import

I am trying to connect all of pages in my application through button menu. I have imported the forms into the main page and am in the process of creating if/else statements for button response but I have noticed that when I run the main page, all of the other forms pop up even though they have not been called yet.

Even when I completely git rid of my response function they still pop up. Is there another way I am meant to import them or have I imported them the correct way?
This is the code I have written (I have not yet completed the response function and added the '*FILE*' as the else statement as a spacer for now).

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import Memberships
import Search
import Fitness
import Help

sg.theme('LightGray1') #add colour 
default_color = 'dark red'

#menu definiton
menu_def = ['&File', ['&Memberships', '&Search', '&Fitness', '&Help']]
menu = [[sg.Column([[sg.ButtonMenu('File', menu_def, key = '_FILE_')]]),
     sg.Button('Exit', key='_EXIT_')]]

title = [[sg.Column([[sg.Text('Main Screen', size = (30,1), text_color = 'red', font = 'Helvetica, 25', justification = 'center')]])]]

#Response to buttonmenu
def formresponse(self, choice):
    if choice==1:
          Memberships
    elif choice==2:
          Search
    elif choice==3:
          Fitness
    elif choice==4:
          Help
    else:
        '_FILE_'

#define layout
layout = [
    [title],
    [menu],
]

#define window
window = sg.Window('City Gym Memberships', 
               layout, size = (225,225),
               default_element_size=(12,1),
               default_button_element_size=(12,1))

#create event loop
while True:
event, values = window.read()
if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit', '_EXIT_'):
             break
if event == '_FILE_':
       formresponse()
print(event, values)

window.close()
```

Comment: You have wrong way to import module and cannot call module. Modules will be executed when imported. Try to define a function `func` in your module, import by `from module import func`, then call it by `func()`.